# What does the translate function do in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I know the decode function, however, no idea what the stuff in translate means:

```
decode(translate(cookie_id,'0123456789','') = '','t',cookie_id,null) as cookie_id

decode((translate(pickup_date,'0123456789','') = '--' and length(pickup_date) = 10),'t',pickup_date,null) as pickup_date,
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions216.htm#i1501659

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple.  This expression:

```
translate(cookie_id, '0123456789', '')
```

returns `NULL`.  Oracle treats the empty string as `NULL` and even explicitly warns:

> You cannot use an empty string for to_string to remove all characters
>   in from_string from the return value. Oracle Database interprets the
>   empty string as null, and if this function has a null argument, then
>   it returns null.

So, the first example will alway yield `NULL` for the `cookie_id`.

Quite possibly, the author intended something like:

```
decode(translate(cookie_id, 'a0123456789', 'a'), '', cookie_id, null) as cookie_id
```

This would check to see if `cookie_id` only contains digits and then return the id.  Personally, I find a regular expression easier to follow:

```
(case when regexp_like(cookie_id, '^[0-9]+$') then cookie_id end)
```

And this doesn't have to do funky things to deal with empty strings.